# Django - how to import from a .csv file in memory

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm writing a page to upload a .csv file and import its content into my models. My current view:

```
class ContentImport(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin,View):
    permission_required = 'delivery.change_delivery' 

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):             
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'delivery/content_import.html', { 'form': form })    

    def import_contents(self, f):
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row[0] 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.import_contents(request.FILES['file'].read())
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, "Contents deleted successfully.")
            return redirect(reverse('delivery:delivery-detail', args=[self.kwargs['delivery_id']])) 
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, "Select a file to upload.")
            return redirect(reverse('delivery:delivery-content-import', args=[self.kwargs['delivery_id']]))
```

My question is about the `import_contents` method and the call for it `self.import_contents(request.FILES['file'].read())`. When I `print row[0]` I get the following error: list index out of range.

My idea with this view is to upload a file, not saving it in the server, read the .csv from the memory and create new records in my models. This read from .csv I got from other answers here in stackoverflow.

I think the problem is how I pass the file to the import_contents function or how I read from it. I just can't figure out. Can you help me? If you have a suggestion on how to do it in an easier way, or the right way, let me know.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't call `read()` when you pass to `import_contents`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected results feeding Django File upload object to Python CSV module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396126/unexpected-results-feeding-django-file-upload-object-to-python-csv-module)

Comment: @DanielRoseman It worked, thanks! Now I have to deal with the proper .csv reading. When I use row[0] it returns the whole line, not the column 0. But that's a thing I need to figure out now.

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem.

```
self.import_contents(request.FILES['file'].read())
```

`csv.reader()` expects a file like object, not its content.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396126/unexpected-results-feeding-django-file-upload-object-to-python-csv-module?rq=1) can definitely be construed as a related answer.

Comment: As Daniel commented in my question calling without the .read() works. Now I'm working with the import. When I call row[0] it returns the whole line, not the column 0. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: cool. but the current `csv.reader()` issue could be debugged much easily on the python/django console. And in case it helps: the difference could be in `delimiter` or `quotechar`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html 

perhaps, dialect option might help for you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The reader is like this now and working as intended: reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';', quotechar='"')